# JQuery UI selectmenu not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to use the JQuery `selectmenu` widget with my select elements. However, they are not displayed correctly. It seems that the `div`s that get wrapped around the select by the `selectmenu` widget are not being put in the right place. These divs should appear in the section I have highlighted, wrapped around the select elements. They are instead appearing several lines below this, where I have outlined in red. Does anyone know why this is happening, or what I am doing wrong?

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id = 'hide'><input type='hidden' id='modelid'>
        <label for='model'>Model</label><br>
        <input id='model' type='text' name='model' tabindex=2 />
        <input type='hidden' id='input'><br>
        <label for='man'>Manufacturer</label><br>
        <select id='man' name='manufacturerid' tabindex=3>
            <option value='' selected > Select Manufacturer</option>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT manufacturerid,`code`,`name` AS manufacturer 
                FROM manufacturer ORDER BY manufacturer;";
                $manufacturerResult = mysql_query($sql);
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($manufacturerResult)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$record['manufacturerid']."'>".$record['manufacturer']."</option>";
                }   
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <label for='itemtype'>Inventory Type</label><br>
        <select id='itemtype' name='inventorytypeid' tabindex=4>
            <option value='' selected > Select Part Type</option>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT inventorytypeid,`name` AS inventorytype 
                FROM inventorytype WHERE active = 'True' ORDER BY inventorytype;";
                $inventorytypeResult = mysql_query($sql);
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($inventorytypeResult)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$record['inventorytypeid']."'>".$record['inventorytype']."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <input id='active' type='checkbox' name='activate' tabindex=5 />
        <label for='active'>Active</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$( "#search, #update, #add, #back" ).button();
$('select').selectmenu();
```

I would also like to add that the tabs and buttons display correctly; the only thing not working is the selectmenu.

And finally, here is the image:
[image]

Comment: can you put a reference to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized my issue: I recently switched from JQuery UI 1.10 to 1.11, but forgot to update my css theme to 1.11 as well.